# I cannot figure out what permission I am missing in AWS IAM to allow firewall rule editing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am attempting to create a policy and no matter which variations I try it is not working.

I simply want to the user to be able to edit inbound/outbound rules in a security group. I eventually gave up trying to specify a resource just to rule that out as a cause.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress",
            "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
            "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
            "ec2:UpdateSecurityGroupRuleDescriptionsEgress",
            "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
            "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupEgress",
            "ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup",
            "ec2:UpdateSecurityGroupRuleDescriptionsIngress"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:DescribeInstanceAttribute",
            "ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus",
            "ec2:DescribeInstances",
            "ec2:DescribeNetworkAcls",
            "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
}
```

Here is what the user is seeing
[image]

I can confirm the user is correctly added to the policy, because as a test I gave the user literally all permissions to everything and it worked fine and showed the inbound rules.

I have even tried the AWS documentation and it is telling me some of the permissions do not even exist: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-ec2-console.html

`"ec2:DescribeSecurityGroupsRules"` to be exact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that `DescribeSecurityGroupRules` was added 2 days prior to you writing this question!

See: [Easily Manage Security Group Rules with the New Security Group Rule ID | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/easily-manage-security-group-rules-with-the-new-security-group-rule-id/)

That would explain why existing documentation does not references these permissions.

Therefore, I would recommend adding permission for `ec2:DescribeSecurityGroupRules` and `ec2:ModifySecurityGroupRules`.

It is always tricky getting permissions right for the console, because it isn't easy to know all the API calls being made by the console. We are lucky in this case that the console mentioned the required permissions! Sometimes you can discover the API calls being made by examining the AWS CloudTrail logs.

Comment: Thanks for the help, while specifically that permission still did not work, I learned a few things from your post. 

1. That this was a brand new issue (I was even going to write in my original post that I could swear I had this working before).

2. Just because AWS gives me an error does not mean they are correct :). I ended up adding DescribeSecurityGroupRules and ModifySecurityGroupRules

If you've like to modify your post for those permission I will answer it as correct

Comment: Also note: it was DescribeSecurityGroupRules not DescribeSecurityGroupsRules that worked, I got that from your link